# Javascript / CSS - fading in an image which doesn't appear?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, fadein

When my webpage loads, I want there to be links. Once all the links are clicked, I want an image to fade in on the bottom of the page (the image says 'complete' which basically means the user has completed clicking all the links). I first hide the image when the webpage loads, like so;

```
<html>
    <body>
        <!-- links which need to be clicked go here -->
        <img id='complete' src='../images/complete.png' alt='' />
    </body>
</html>

<style>
    #complete {
        visibility: hidden;
    }
</style>

<script>
    // once all links are clicked
    $('#complete').fadeIn();
</script>
```

With this code, #complete does not fade in (probably because visiblity is set to hidden). I tried making visiblity set to visible right before the fade in command but that still didn't make it fade in. I also tried making the css

```
#complete {
    filter: alpha(opacity = 0);
}
```

and the script

```
$('#complete').fadeTo('slow', '100');
```

and that doesn't work, #complete just appears really fast rather than fading in slowly.
I am using IE8 with CSS, any idea on how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

on css

```
#complete {
display: none;
}
```

and on javascript

```
$('#complete').fadeIn();
```

And try to use latest jquery

```
<body>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
</body>
```

See it on action: http://jsfiddle.net/KUqJL/ your problem is what I said about css

Answer (score 1):

`#complete {
        visibility: hidden;
    }` replace with: `display:none`

Answer (score 1):

Change your css to:

```
#complete {
    display:none;
}
```

and if you'd like to use `.fadeTo()`, the second parameter must be an integer between 0 and 1.

```
$('#complete').fadeTo("slow", 1);
```

"slow" could also be replaced with a millisecond value such as 3000 (3 seconds), for an even slower fade.

```
$('#complete').fadeTo(3000, 1);
```

Here is a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/89fNY/) that may help.

Answer (score 0):

[`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility) cannot be animated. Something is either visible or hidden, there are no middle stages.

But you can achieve this effect by using [`opacity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) instead of [`visibility`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/visibility), since visible elements have an [`opacity`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/opacity) between 0 and 1.

```
#complete {
    visibility: visible; /* this is the default so this line is not required */
    opacity: 0;
}
```

And use the [`.animate()`](http://api.jquery.com/animate/) method.

```
$('#complete').animate({
    opacity: 1.0
}, 'slow');
```

jQuery has methods like [`.fadeIn()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeto/) [`.fadeTo()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeto/) and [`.fadeOut()`](http://api.jquery.com/fadeout/) which animates opacity with the addition of setting the `display` property to `none` on 0 opacity and vica-versa when animating.

Since `display: none` not only makes elements invisible, but collapses them (width and height are 0 and the element is not part of the layout), I think the `opacity` property is more suitable for you.

---

This can also be done with CSS transitions:

```
#complete {
    opacity: 0;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.8s linear;
    -o-transition: opacity 0.8s linear;
    -webkit-transition: opacity 0.8s linear;
    transition: opacity 0.8s linear;
}
#complete.fadedIn {
    opacity: 1;
}
```

And the JavaScript than changes to:

```
$('#complete').addClass('fadedIn');
```